# Error Using Drive Mount with Google Colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I had been working on Colab using:

```py
from google.colab import drive 
.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

with no problems, until today.

I don't know why this error was raised:

```py
Go to this URL in a browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=947318989803-6bn6qk8qdgf4n4g3pfee6491hc0brc4i.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth%3a2.0%3aoob&scope=email%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fdocs.test%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fdrive%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fdrive.photos.readonly%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fpeopleapi.readonly&response_type=code

Enter your authorization code:
··········
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TIMEOUT                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d05fe204dd76> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import drive
----> 2 drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server)
    223         oauth_prompt,
    224         problem_and_stopped,
--> 225         drive_exited,
    226     ])
    227     if case == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py in expect(self, pattern, timeout, searchwindowsize, async_, **kw)
    342         compiled_pattern_list = self.compile_pattern_list(pattern)
    343         return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list,
--> 344                 timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
    345 
    346     def expect_list(self, pattern_list, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py in expect_list(self, pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize, async_, **kw)
    370             return expect_async(exp, timeout)
    371         else:
--> 372             return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
    373 
    374     def expect_exact(self, pattern_list, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py in expect_loop(self, timeout)
    179             return self.eof(e)
    180         except TIMEOUT as e:
--> 181             return self.timeout(e)
    182         except:
    183             self.errored()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py in timeout(self, err)
    142             exc = TIMEOUT(msg)
    143             exc.__cause__ = None    # in Python 3.x we can use "raise exc from None"
--> 144             raise exc
    145 
    146     def errored(self):

TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x7f58fb7ab4e0>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile('google.colab.drive MOUNTED')
    1: re.compile('root@e7a376888b95-b97a84955c154714b7850ceb4ecf0e8e: ')
    2: re.compile('(Go to this URL in a browser: https://.*)$')
    3: re.compile('Drive File Stream encountered a problem and has stopped')
    4: re.compile('drive EXITED')
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x7f58fb7ab4e0>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile('google.colab.drive MOUNTED')
    1: re.compile('root@e7a376888b95-b97a84955c154714b7850ceb4ecf0e8e: ')
    2: re.compile('(Go to this URL in a browser: https://.*)$')
    3: re.compile('Drive File Stream encountered a problem and has stopped')
    4: re.compile('drive EXITED')
```

As everyone knows, this code opens a new tab where you have to select a Google account, click on the 'Allow' button, and copy a long password to Colab

**EDIT:**

I tried to do the same in another way with:

```py
#Installing PyDrive
!pip install PyDrive

#Importing modules
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

#Authenticating and creating the PyDrive client
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#Getting the file
downloaded2 = drive.CreateFile({'id':"1QGtoo1wqCP2yrjl8kFu4kTfjWqh3EOdt"})   # replace the id with id of file you want to access
downloaded2.GetContentFile('estructura_cc_felipe.xlsx')
```

But it raises this error:

```py
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&code_challenge=WkM1RS8Flu1_txc3jn4V_FfutgZuRaHSzYbDvs134PM&code_challenge_method=S256&access_type=offline&response_type=code&prompt=select_account


Enter verification code: ··········
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AuthorizationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bb96e063f8ef> in <module>()
      6 
      7 #Authenticating and creating the PyDrive client
----> 8 auth.authenticate_user()
      9 gauth = GoogleAuth()
     10 gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/auth.py in authenticate_user(clear_output)
    147     context_manager = _output.temporary if clear_output else _noop
    148     with context_manager():
--> 149       _gcloud_login()
    150     _install_adc()
    151     colab_tpu_addr = _os.environ.get('COLAB_TPU_ADDR', '')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/auth.py in _gcloud_login()
     97     _os.remove(name)
     98   if gcloud_process.returncode:
---> 99     raise _errors.AuthorizationError('Error fetching credentials')
    100 
    101 

AuthorizationError: Error fetching credentials
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? I have been working for a long time importing files located on my Google drive and never had these problems.

Comment: I get the same error today and it always worked without problem also for me.

Comment: Same for me. Even switching to my second university account didn't help

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1540

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It turns out that if you manually copy the auth code from the auth button instead of clicking the copy button, it works

Comment: I tried manual copy-pasting. I also copy-pasted it on notepad and then again copy-pasted it in google colab. Still facing the same problem, any guesses why

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you can try:

As of the new (messed up) update you can not mount using **drive._mount** anymore (or at least for now). So what you can do is either copy your folder/directory from your other google drive to your current google drive (the account you are logging in to colab with) OR you can simply log out from colab and log in with your Google account that has the drive you want to mount to

**Remember**
use **drive.mount** and not **drive._mount** after following the above guideline